# Grant access for user to folder (even files created after permission is granted)

Tags: permissions, users, setfacl

I have created a backup-user (let's just call it `jeremy`) on an Ubuntu-server.

Then I've created a `backup`-dir, containing files from several different servers:

```
/backup
   |
   |--server1
   |     |--daily_backup
   |     |--weekly_backup
   |
   |--server2
   |     |--daily_backup
   |     |--weekly_backup
```

I've then granted access to the `backup`-dir for `jeremy` with the following command:

```
setfacl -R -m u:jeremy:rwx backup/
```

However... If I login with the root-user and create a new directory, for instance: `/backup/server2/monthly_backup`, then `jeremy` won’t have access to the folder.

Is there a way to make it so that both `root` and `jeremy` can read, write and execute everything in the `/backup`-directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One must remember to create a default mask for all new filesystem objects as well.

```
setfacl -d -m u:jeremy:rwx backup/
```

Comment: Awesome! I do need the `-R`-flag, in order for it to take effect on subfolders as well. So `setfacl -R -d -m u:jeremy:rwx backup/` did the job.